# Weird Kirchhoffs laws circuit

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

See image - I dont have any idea on how to start calculating this circuit using Kirchhoffs laws. There isnt any kind of this circuit anywhere on the web as far as I can see. I would be very thankful if someone had a formula (sorry for my english, but what I mean is something like this U(V)=R*I to calculate with). You cant make a triangle out of three resistors cuz of the power source between them (as far as I know), the resistors arent in parallel either. I know I firstly need to calculate R, then use 1. Kirchhoffs law on joints/points (?), then write circuit mesh 1 and 2 and from those formulas calculate all the currents. But the best thing about this is that Ive never in my school calculated this type of circuit (believe me, I would have just asked my classmates if they knew the answer to this).

node where all currents go to: I3-I1-I2=0 => I3=I1+I2

S1: -V1+I1*(R1+R5)+I3*R3=0=-2.1+I1*45+(I1+I2)*15

S2: +V2-I2*(R2+R4)+I3*R3=0=1.8-I2*20+(I1+I2)*15

Still working on how to calculate using two unknowns

Those should be the results:

I1=24,8 mA

I2=40,8 mA

I3=65,6 mA

[image: ss]

Comment: Hint 1: This will be easier to solve with KVL than KCL. Hint 2: start by finding the fundamental meshes.

Comment: The weird part is only how it was mis-drawn for conventional logic diagrams.  But don't let that stop you in using KVL  or KCL http://tinyurl.com/y6c3wozz

Comment: Weid draw: yeah R3 should be a straight line but I dont know how to do that on the circuit drawer I used.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/y3czrpl7  rev A  use "w" to draw wire, "r' for resistor or use menu

Comment: Tom, you should not expect to be taught a special solution for every particular circuit. You should know how to do mesh or nodal analysis to solve any circuit you are presented with. If you are having trouble solving this circuit, you need to go back to basics and re-study the basics of how to do mesh analysis.

Comment: Rev B http://tinyurl.com/y6dam3qy

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis#Setting_up_the_equations

Comment: thanks for simulations, but I need to have calculations on paper not just exact values - about me knowing mesh on any circuit, I would appreciate if you could point out where in mesh Ive made a mistake, and about restudying - I cant REstudy if I didnt study it right? Im studying it right now, thats why Im writing here - and I could do a "normal" or more common circuit, but this is completely new for me

Comment: You can also use Superposition theorem to solve this linear circuit. You can refer following link to get more details about Superposition Theorem. [Superposition theorem explained](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/superposition-theorem/)

Comment: well maybe I could, but it doesnt ring a bell, and I definitely cant solve a task with things that we didnt even learn

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I usually do is redraw such schematics so that they make a little more sense.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv6ohD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can analyze this in a number of ways. My preference is nodal analysis, which depends more on KCL. Mesh analysis is more about KVL. Both work. The above schematic has been prepared for either method.

### Nodal

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_A}{R_3}+\frac{V_A}{R_4}+\frac{V_A}{R_5}&=\frac{V_B}{R_3}+\frac{V_2}{R_4}+\frac{V_D}{R_5}\\\\
\frac{V_B}{R_1}+\frac{V_B}{R_2}+\frac{V_B}{R_3}&=\frac{V_C}{R_1}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_2}+\frac{V_A}{R_3}\\\\
\frac{V_D}{R_5}&=I_1+\frac{V_A}{R_5}\\\\
\frac{V_C}{R_1}+I_1&=\frac{V_B}{R_1}\\\\
V_D&=V_C+V_1
\end{align*}$$

The above analysis provides you with all the voltages and one current. But with the voltages you can work out the rest.

### Mesh

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\text{V}+V_2-I_2\cdot R_4-\left(I_1+I_2\right)\cdot R_3-I_2\cdot R_2&=0\:\text{V}\\\\
V_C+V_1-I_1\cdot R_5-\left(I_1+I_2\right)\cdot R_3-I_1\cdot R_1&=V_C
\end{align*}$$

The above analysis provides you with the two indicated currents. You can work out the rest from there.

### Summary

You can easily see that the current through \$R_3\$ is the sum of \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$. It's not something you need to directly solve for, since it falls out once you know the other two currents.

Since there is no possible loop for \$I_3\$, you can't use it to develop a new loop equation. It's an outcome of the other two loops.

Comment: I edited mine post before I saw your reply, are my calculations for I1 and I2 right?

Comment: @Tom No, they are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have two current variables: \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$, the two mesh currents. All the other current variables you wrote in your equations can be written in terms of these two variables.

For example, what you wrote as \$I_5\$ is just another name for \$I_1\$.

Also, notice that you assigned a reference direction to your mesh 2 so that \$I_2\$ the mesh current will be the opposite of \$I_2\$ the current asked for in the problem. That will only cause confusion.

You could rename your meshes A and B instead of 1 and 2, so that \$I_2 = -I_B\$, or you could use the opposite direction convention for your mesh 2 so that \$I_2\$ refers to the same current whether you take it to mean the mesh current or the current through R2.

Comment: Thats what my workbook or whatever says, if it wants 3 currents, it gets 3 currents! :D And about I5, as I said, this is the best I can do, we never ever calculated this circuit and now our teacher decides that this is the homework for us for some reason. So I definitely need I1, I2 and I3 - those I5 and others idk if I know how maybe I will change that

Comment: @Tom, after you know your mesh currents, you can trivially calculate \$I_3\$ (or use KCL at the node where the three named currents meet).

Comment: I3-I2-I1=0 - KCL at that node right? the mesh currents? sorry but I dont really understand - what I need to do is have one current going in mesh A (IA), and one current going in mesh B (IB)? And from IA and IB I should be able to calculate other currents? thanks

Comment: @Tom, you need to review whatever materials/books/lessons/homework you were given to teach mesh or loop analysis.This site is not capable of replacing your textbooks and lectures.

Answer (score 0):

If we take the currents in the outer branches, \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$, as the mesh currents, then it's easy to see by KCL either node that \$I_3 = I_1 + I_2\$. In usual mesh analysis this current shared between meshes doesn't get a variable name, but it still needs to be used in the KVL equations as the current through the shared branch. The KVL loop equations then end up being

Bottom Loop: \$ \quad (12\Omega+8\Omega)I_2 - 1.8V +15\Omega I_3 =0\$

Top Loop: \$ \quad -(10\Omega+35\Omega)I1 + 2.1V - 15\Omega I_3 = 0\$

These equations along with the the one derived from KCL above give us three equations for three unknowns so we can solve for the three currents. I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: So I basically totally got lost in this and forgot about I3 even existing, Im ashamed of myself, I hope I can now finish this on my own, I will post my calculation here after hoping that this time it will finally be fine :D

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative resolution:**

The resistance seen by the source V1 is R1 in series with R5 and R3 in parallel with R2 + R4. Hence you can compute the fraction of I1 pushed by V1. Then momentarily considering V2 = 0, I1 is split in I2/I3 in the inverse proportion of the resistances R3 and R 2 + R4.

You can repeat this computation for the current pushed by V2, assuming V1 = 0.

Then you sum both contributions. This method derives from the principle of superposition.